# Load code from string without using loadstring() function

Tags: lua, fivem

There is any way to load code from string without using a loadstring() function?

For example:

```
local code = {
    {
        Code = [[
            function DoSomething()
                print('making something')
            end
        ]]
    },
    {
        Code = [[
            function DoSomethingElse()
                print('making something else')
            end
        ]]
    },
}

for i = 1, #code do
    local currentCode = code[i].Code
    -- Load this code here, without loadstring()
end
```

App where I'm writing uses a Lua version that doesn't have the loadstring() function. There is a load() function, which works the same way, but it is not a safe way to load code. It can be easily intercepted. I would like to keep my code as secure as possible.

Comment: What version of lua are you using? does https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load work for what you need?

Comment: Since when it's not safe? loadstring was basically merged with load.

Comment: You should test whether `load` was redefined before invoking it.  Some Lua obfuscators do such test.

Comment: „A modified version of Lua 5.3 is used in FiveM, called CfxLua. This version includes some of the modifications the Grit game engine introduced:
Support for relative path literals
Support for vectors & quaternions”. Load function is not safe, because code can dumped.

Comment: @MuDzYn. your concern is from `string.dump`? this can be used on any function not only on functions made with `load`. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.dump

Comment: what are you actually afraid of?

Comment: I don't mean string.dump(). The application in which this environment is an extension of GTA: V, unfortunately it is quite flawed, so people with the appropriate software can dump code from the load() function.

Comment: So are you also avoiding `require`?

Comment: print(require) -> nil :/